# dijit.form.FilteringSelect with substring search

Tags: dojo

dijit.form.FilteringSelect is close to what I need. I've tried lots of ways to do what I want, but being a dijit beginner I never know if I'm even going in the right direction.

When I start typing in a FilteringSelect, I only see the options starting with what I typed. Like a query on `value + "*"`
What I need is to see any option that has what I type anywhere. Like a query on `"*" + value + "*"`

So if there is "Apple", "Banana" and "Orange", and I type "e", I should see "Apple" and "Orange". If possible, with the search string emphasized: "Appl**e**", "Orang**e**"

I think I need some clever data storage, but anywhere I go looks like a dead end. Am I missing something, or should I do this in a completely different way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to use the `queryExpr` attribute:

```
var f = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
 ...
 queryExpr: "*${0}*",
 ...
}, node);
```

Notice the * before and after the ${0}.

Comment: Note that if you set `queryExpr` to anything other than the default (start of the search term) you may also want to set `searchDelay: 1000` (1 sec or so) b/c each time it searches, it overwrites what the user typed w/ the top term.

Comment: Alternative to the delay, you can set `autoComplete` to false. https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/13915

Answer (score 4):

Hey! You need to add queryExpr="*${0}*" to the filteringselect component.

By default, it's ${0}*  , meaning it searches strings that start with what you typed.

As a hint for others, in JSP, I had to change the query expr. to queryExpr="*\${0}*" .

Comment: the docs also suggest that you should use `highlightMatch="all"` in conjunction with this (but it doesn't seem to work quite right for me as of dojo1.3)

Answer (score 0):

In our project we solved this problem with a patch to `dojo.data.util.filter` overwriting `patternToRegExp` method.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of time trying I could make it run, Mada tip was correct but miss the * before and after. The correct queryStr (in JSP) is `'*\${0}*'`