# Dojo Filtering Select Filtering

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

Is there a way to include the entire value in the filtering search? For example, searching “123″ would return the value “Test 123″. By default, the control only filters starting with the first character.

I tried modifying the queryExpr property mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094232/dijit-form-filteringselect-with-substring-search), but nothing seemed to work for me. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dijit.form.FilteringSelect with substring search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094232/dijit-form-filteringselect-with-substring-search)

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is 2 years ago but I'm just answering in case someone else comes along looking!

You can specify the queryExpr like this:

```
<xe:djFilteringSelect id="djFilteringSelect1" value="#{viewScope.myvalue}" autoComplete="false">
    <xe:this.queryExpr><![CDATA[${javascript:"*$\{0}*"}]]></xe:this.queryExpr>
    <xp:selectItems id="selectItems1" value="#{myBean.mySelectItems}"/>
</xe:djFilteringSelect>
```